# MongoDB not returning all results with find $in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I have a simple query to find multiple documents matching a field `jId`.  Right now there are just 2 documents.  Using `node-mongodb-native` and calling `find` with an `$in` flag limits it to only one though:

```
let collection = db.collection('documents')

// Without $in, both are returned
collection
  .find()
  .toArray((err, docs) => {
    docs.map((doc) => doc.jId)) // Gives ['j-04e347','j-548240']
  })

// With $in, only one is returned
collection
  .find({ 'jId': { '$in': [ 'j-04e347',' j-548240' ] } })
  .toArray((err, docs) => {
    docs.map((doc) => doc.jId)) // Gives ['j-04e347']
  })
```

Is this a bug, or am I using the `$in` operator incorrectly, or does the `node-mongodb-native` package not support this?

If `$in` is not usable, is there another way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Have you tried executing the query directly through the mongo shell to rule out any possibility of issues in the app?

Comment: @AdamHarrison yes; using the shell or Robomongo both yield the correct result (2 documents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an extra space getting included: `' j-548240'` instead of `'j-548240'`.

Ugh. But this does indeed work in `node-mongodb-native`.